# Sorting the items in repeated field of a message in Google Protocol Buffers

Tags: c++, protocol-buffers

Is there an implementation in the protocol buffers library that allows sorting the array that's specified as a repeated field? For e.g., say the array consists of items of a type that itself contains an index field based on which the array items need to be sorted.
I couldn't find it, so guess I'll have to write one myself. Just wanted to confirm.
Thanks.

Comment: That just... *isn't protobuf's job*; if you want the data sorted, sort it *before* you get near the serializer. The serializer's job is to get the data to bytes and back again, preserving semantics like order.

Comment: @MarcGravell, actually I was hoping I wouldn't have to make a copy of the same data in my application code and then offload it into the protobuf, but to have sorted info I guess I'll have to. Thanks.

Answer (score 25):

Protobufs provide a RepeatedPtr interface, via the mutable_* methods, which can be sorted with the std::sort() template.

Unless the underlying type of the repeated field is a simple one, you'll likely want to use an overloaded operator<, comparator, or lambda to do so. An toy example using a lambda would be:

```
message StaffMember {
    optional string name = 1;
    optional double hourly_rate = 2;
}

message StoreData {
    repeated StaffMember staff = 1;
}

StoreData store;
// Reorder the list of staff by pay scale
std::sort(store.mutable_staff()->begin(),
          store.mutable_staff()->end(),
          [](const StaffMember& a, const StaffMember& b){
             return a.hourly_rate() < b.hourly_rate();
          });
```

Comment: Very handy to be able to use sort with the store examples. Worked perfectly for me! Thanks!